# MySQL vs JSON vs Firebase as a database option

Tags: javascript, php, json, firebase

I am currently developing a site to track credits gained from exams, and how these stack up against the user's goal credits.
I know JavaScript fairly well, but don't know any PHP.
What would be the best option to use as a database? Please, I am a beginner and I will be getting answers from advanced programmers. To me, your opinions count so please don't close this as asking for opinions.

**MySQL**

I could use this on a PHP site, but it would involve me learning PHP. What are the benefits and would they outweigh the hassle of learning a whole new language?

**JSON**

Would it work if I used JSON files for data storage, and used `xmlHttpRequest()` to read and write information?

**Firebase**

Would Firebase work as a fully operating database?

Comment: If you know JavaScript, you should consider node.js + mongodb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know javasript very well and aren't willing to learn a new server side language, I would recommend using Firebase. They way it works is very similar to if you had built your own REST api and just made ajax calls to it.

I wouldnt recommend using json to store data. Anytime you want to read there would be more data sent over the network than necessary and when you get enough data it would be impractical. Databases exist to avoid storing data in a file and simply reading/writing to the file.

Using php wouldnt be the best idea. It is a very powerful language, but it is incredibly easy to write major bugs with it. If you were to use it I would recommend learning a web framework because it would fix most of the bugs that you would write yourself. Heres a list of a bunch of php frameworks http://www.phpframeworks.com/. I think that there would be more benefits to you actually learning php. For starters, every developer should have more than 1 language in their toolbox. You should be able to approach a problem and know what the best way to solve it is and that starts with the exposure to different languages and technologies. Learning another language will take a decent amount of time, but you will get much more out of it than releasing your site a little bit earlier.

So to sum it up, I would use php(or any other scripting language for that matter) with a web framework. Your site would be more secure with the web framework and you will become a much better, more valuable developer by taking the time to learn something new.